# How to use Excel as datasource and execute SQL Query in UIPath

Tags: excel, uipath

I am trying to connect Excel as datasource in UIPath. But getting some error. I did some research and found following post
[UIPathForum](https://forum.uipath.com/t/excel-database-connection/22524)

But still it is not helpful getting same error as mentioned.
I am looking for correct connection string for xlsx or xls and Sample select SQL query.

My Excel file looks like below 
C:\Source.xlsx

Worksheet name - Sheet1

```
ID  |   F_Name  |   Score
1   |   Hemant  |   12
2   |   ABC     |   34
3   |   ERT     |   12
```

I have tried following Connection string and SQL Query

```
Connection String : - "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Source.xlsx";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"

SQL Query : - "Select * from Sheet1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this :
Connection String : =

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Source.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml"

SQL Query : - "select * from [Sheet1$]"

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change your syntax in the SQL query from what you have:

```
SELECT * FROM Sheet1
```

to this one

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]
```

Comment: Thanks I will have noted